# Display issue prevents opening GUI in Debian 10

Tags: debian, display

I updated my OS to Linux Debian 10 from 9. And I'm having a big issue when trying to start any graphical interface. I get the message: "cannot open display". 
I worked out in the OS updates already. 
The computer isn't new, but it was running perfectly with Debian 8 and 9 in the past. Now it looks like there is an issue with my VGA display driver or similar. I have an AMD Kabini Radeon HD 8400 series display. The Kernel driver in use is Radeon and the Kernel modules used are Radeon and Amdpu, according to the command lspci -nnk | grep -i -EA3 “3d|display|vga”. 
There is no hardware issue, since I can run Windows 10 on that computer too. 
Does anybody know what to do? 
Thanks.